# Internet connection lost for a second every ~hour

Tags: internet-connection, connection

Every hour or so, my internet seems to disconnect for a second. I know it because I get kicked from every multiplier game with some kind of "network/connection error". I tried downloading a large file and see it will stop same time I the game kicks me out, and it did!

The internet connection is restored instantly, I can go to the browser and there is no problem.

I tried the same with another computer and it seems that the main one is the only one that it happens on. I have no idea what can possibly be causing it.

Comment: Verify the problem is not the router/modem.

Comment: @Ramhound how can I do that?

Comment: @llyaD - Use a different modem/router verify the problem still happens.  If it doesn't then replace the hardware, if it does, contact your ISP for technical assistance.

Comment: can you give more details? Computer and network card brand/model, operating system, how you connect to the internet (router? modem? cellular phone? )

Comment: A have a PC with an onboard LAN connection - Asroc h61m - and a Netgear router DGN2200

Answer (score 0):

If you get your IP address by DHCP, it could be that you get assigned a new address each hour or so. In Linux, dhclient-leases(5) should tell you where the file containing the data on the current lease lives, it isn't too hard to understand what it means.

Comment: I use win7 and I gave that computer a static IP through the router

Comment: Perhaps the "intermitent Internet" problem's cause is upstream (I.e., the address assignation to your router? Some quirk of your ISP?). A http://www.bufferbloat.net problem?

Comment: I called my ISP and ADLS line provider, bot say they see no disconnects on their side

Comment: Could there be such short disconnects that are not full disconnects from the network?